# What will pro jobs entail?

Tags: payday-2

It looks like some of the heists have a "pro" version.  Pro jobs are glowing red on the crime.net's map and seem to feature better rewards.

[image: Red glowing pro job on the crime.net map]

So far I only tried the pro version of Bank in which you have to steal gold instead of dollars.  Gold being heavier, your speed is quite reduced while carrying the bags, making the mission more difficult.

Regarding the gameplay itself, is it the only difference with the "regular" mission ?  What are the differences in the other "pro" missions ?  Are there any prerequisite to get access to these pro jobs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no prerequisites for pro jobs (I saw them from the lowest reputation levels). The difference in comparison to normal jobs is that you *cannot* try the mission again if you fail. You get one try and that's it.

Another thing that makes pro jobs special is that there are no pro jobs on normal difficulty. They are always on hard, very hard or overkill.